# vscode do not automatically put current word into find

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I cmd+f in vscode it automatically puts the current word i'm typing into the find box. I would like it to not do that and preserve the last thing I was typing instead as I usually need to do multiple finds and am editing them all. Where's the setting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this to false: `editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection`, true is the default.

Comment: How do you edit this? I can't find this in the interfeace (Options Dialog, etc.)

Comment: It is one of the settings.  Gear Icon/Settings or File/Preferences/Settins and search for `find` and `seed`. There is no "Options Dialog" in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Current version of vscode (1.70.2) has `editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection` options listed as `never`, `always` (default), and `selection`. I find `selection` to be the most intuitive (i.e. only seed search string from the editor selection)

Answer (score 1):

1. On the Options Menu, go into 'Environment' then 'Find and Replace'.
2. Uncheck "Automatically populate Find What with text from the editor".

[image]

Comment: How is it possibile? As Mark said (on the same day with you) "There is no "Options Dialog" in Visual Studio Code." It seems you show the wrong tool.